# I'm having trouble creating an API Post using Python flask, SQL workbench and Postman

Tags: python, mysql, post, postman

I have a table named 'gem' in SQL Workbench and already have a working connection. When I try to add another gem using Postman, I get an error "tuple" object has no attribute 'encode'. I'm still a beginner and can't tell what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?
These are my imports for the files I used. 'creds' is a file with my credentials to connect with my username and password to my db. 'sql' is the file that has the connection to MYSQL Workbench.

```
import flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from sql import create_connection
from sql import execute_read_query
import creds
```

This is my sql file for the connection the db

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def create_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            database=db_name
        )
        print("Connection to MySQL DB successful")
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
    return connection

def execute_read_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    result = None
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
    except Error as e:
        print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
```

```
@app.route('/api/gem', methods=['POST'])
def add_example():
    request_data = request.get_json()
    newid = request_data['id']
    newgemtype = request_data['gemtype']
    newgemcolor = request_data['gemcolor']
    newcarat = request_data['carat']
    newprice = request_data['price']
    myCreds = creds.Creds()
    conn = create_connection(myCreds.conString, myCreds.userName, myCreds.password, myCreds.dbName)
    sql = "INSERT INTO gem(id, gemtype, gemcolor, carat, price) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (newid, newgemtype, newgemcolor, newcarat, newprice)
    gem = execute_read_query(conn, sql)
    results = []
    gem.append({'id': newid, 'gemtype': newgemtype, 'gemcolor': newgemcolor, 'carat': newcarat, 'price': newprice})
    return 'add request successful'
```

Comment: sql = "INSERT  and the rest have to be a string, so you need to use string replacement, your construct, is so not possible

Comment: What is string replacement? I've never used that before.

Comment: see here https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/python-placeholder/

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code for the `execute_read_query` function, and the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I added the execute_read_query function for you to see it. I'm unable to get the complete error right now.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.execute` expects either a single argument - a string - or two arguments, a string and a sequence of parameters.

`sql = "INSERT INTO gem(id, gemtype, gemcolor, carat, price) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (newid, newgemtype, newgemcolor, newcarat, newprice)` is a single `tuple`.  `cursor.execute` recognises that it has received a single argument and tries to encode it, leading to the error.

The solution is to unpack the arguments:

```py
cursor.execute(*query)
```

or pass them separately:

```py
cursor.execute(sql_string, params)
```